# Promise и inquirer не понимаю почему не работает

Tags: javascript, node.js

Не понимаю почему код отрабатывает не корректно, вопрос задаётся, но поле для ввода ответа не появляется, а программа заканчивает работу, мне кажется, что проблема с ассенхронностью

```
const readline = require('readline');
const path = require('path');
const res = require('express/lib/response');

const r1 = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
})



const questions1 = (question) => {
    return new Promise(res => {
        r1.question(question,answer=>{
            res(answer)
        })    
    })
}


    
const ques = async ()=>
inquirer 
    .prompt ([
        {
        name: 'fileName',
        type: 'list', // input, number, confirm, list, chackbox, password
        message: 'Выберите интересующую вас хрень',
        choices: ['Добавить новость', 'Удалить новость'],
        },
    ])
    .then(async ({fileName})=>{
        return new Promise(res=>{
            questions1("Задайте Вопрос \n")
        }).then(answer=>console.log(answer))
    })
    

ques();
```

```
? Выберите интересующую вас хрень Добавить новость
Задайте Вопрос
aleksejpasenko@MacBook-Air-Aleksej news %
```

**Сижу и туплю уже пол дня, помогите, пожалуйста!!**

Comment: некорректно написан вызов `questions1("Задайте Вопрос \n")`, нужно так https://pastebin.com/4WyidMcn

Comment: nörbörnën, cпасибо огромное!! А почему не работает, если я инициализирую r1 вне questions1?

Comment: r1 можно инициализировать в любом месте до объявления `const questions1`, например, там где он инициализирован в вопросе. но так как r1 одноразовый то лучше его инициализировать в той функции, которая задаёт вопрос (пример https://pastebin.com/fEfFDU6C)